# Matlab C++ integration, what is libting?

Tags: c++, matlab, linker

I have written some c++ code that I want to integrate with matlab in the following method https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/publish-interface-to-shared-c-library-on-linux.html

1. The first step: Generate Interface on Linux goes well.
2. The second step: Define Missing Constructs is not really necessary, my example is so simple it can do this automatically
3. Build Interface is where I get the problem.

Here is my matlab code:

```
clc;

clibgen.generateLibraryDefinition(fullfile("testing.h"),...
    "Libraries", fullfile("testing.so"),... 
    "PackageName", "integrationTest",...
    "ReturnCArrays",false,... % treat output as MATLAB arrays
    "Verbose",true)

defineintegrationTest;
summary(defineintegrationTest)
build(defineintegrationTest)
```

The last line, build(defineintegrationTest) is what throws the error. Here is the full output:

> Using g++ compiler. Generated definition file
> defineintegrationTest.mlx and data file 'integrationTestData.xml'
> contain definitions for 1 constructs supported by MATLAB. Build using
> build(defineintegrationTest).
>
> MATLAB Interface to integrationTest Library
>
> Functions int32 clib.integrationTest.addingNumbers(int32,int32)
>
> Building interface file 'integrationTestInterface.so'. Error using
> clibgen.internal.buildHelper (line 62) Build failed with error:
> '/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lting collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit
> status '.
>
> Error in clibgen.LibraryDefinition/build (line 1297)
> clibgen.internal.buildHelper(obj, obj.LibraryInterface, '', directBuild);
>
> Error in myIntegrationTest (line 11) build(defineintegrationTest)

The main part of the error seems to be the cannot find -lting collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status ' part. I made testing.so using the lines:

g++ -o testing.o -O3 testing.cpp

g++ -shared -o testing.so testing.o

My testing examples here are super simple. Here's the cpp file.

```
#include "testing.h"

int addingNumbers(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}
```

And here's the header file

```
#ifndef TESTING_   /* Include guard */
#define TESTING_

int addingNumbers(int a, int b);

#endif
```

I also tried to use g++ to make a shared library with the -lting flag, and got the same error.

g++ -shared -o testing.so testing.o -lting

Does anyone know what this library is or where I can install it? I have gotten google results that actually return 0 results while looking for things about -lting or libting or matlab ting.

Comment: I have no idea what `clibgen` does internally, I have never tried to use it. But `testing.so`, if you assume the first three letters of the library name are "lib", gives you `libting.so`, which you would link with `-lting`. Might I recommend that you give your library a name that starts with "lib", as is customary? `g++ -shared -o libtesting.so testing.o`

Comment: Thank you, this worked and fixed my problem! I very much appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you should make the first three letters of your .so file lib. So I changed testing.so to libtesting.so and reran the same steps and it worked. Thank you for your help Cris Luengo, who answered this question.